# Visualizar base de datos HSQLDB creada por Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring

Como se puede visualizar la base de datos creada en memoria por Spring MVC al usar el código:

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
            .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL)
            .generateUniqueName(true)
            .build();
}
```

Se puede visualizar o manipular esta base de datos con la herramienta HSQL Database Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Sí se puede. Para ver la base de datos en memoria se puede hacer con la siguiente línea en el código. Ponla en un lugar de tu aplicación dónde se ejecute dicha línea (puede ser en un test también).

Cuando pase por esa línea se abrirá una ventana con una interfaz en la que se pueden ver la base de datos y ejecutar sentencias sql.

```
DatabaseManagerSwing.main(new String[] { "--url", "jdbc:hsqldb:mem:dataSource", "--user", "sa", "--password", "" });
```